# MotionLayout only animated after first ACTION_UP

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

I have question about MotionLayout (XML). Im creating horizontal recyclerview inside motionlayout. I have intercept the OnTouch but the transition only working after first ACTION_UP. So first time the screen is opened, animation not working. After i touch it and lift my fingers up which triggers ACTION_UP, then it is working now.

So the flow is like this:
opened the screen -> swipe -> ACTION_MOVE happened, but animation not working -> lift fingers up -> ACTION_UP happened -> swipe again, now animation working.

GIF can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQ3kV.jpg).

Why is it happening and how to solve it?

My onTouchListener

```
binding.rvPoster.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
    Log.d("OnTouchListener", "event: $event")
    binding.motionLayoutHorizontal.onTouchEvent(event)
    return@setOnTouchListener false
}
```

My motionscene:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        app:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        app:duration="1000">
        <KeyFrameSet></KeyFrameSet>
        <OnSwipe
            app:dragDirection="dragEnd"
            app:touchRegionId="@id/rvPoster"
            app:onTouchUp="stop"/>
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start"></ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btnSeeAll" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/rvPoster"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btnSeeAll" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/verticalGuideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

Comment: I am not sure what the problem(s) are but I would start by changing onSwipe 
 <OnSwipe  app:dragDirection="dragStart" app:touchAnchorSide="end" ......

Comment: thanks for your response, unfortunately the problem still exists, i think i might try to open issue